# How to execute complex Arel query in Rails 3 from Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, arel

I'm on Rails 3,and I have a SQL query composed of a few joins that I've built up in Arel. I want to run this query from a method in one of my models, but I'm not sure of how to do this. The arel object turns out to be of type Arel::InnerJoin, and I want to retrieve an array of all objects returned from that query. Do I run ModelName.find_by_sql(my_arel_query_object) in order to do that? Or do I run my_arel_query_object.each {...} and iterate over each tuple in order to pop them into an array manually?

I hope I'm making myself clear. Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Updated: Here is the code I use within my user model:

```
def get_all_ingredients
    restaurants = Table(:restaurants)
    meals = Table(:meals)
    ingredients = Table(:ingredients)

    restaurants_for_user = restaurants.where(restaurants[:user_id].eq(self.id))
    meals_for_user = restaurants_for_user.join(meals).on(restaurants[:id].eq(meals[:restaurant_id]))  
    ingredients_for_user = meals_for_user.join(ingredients).on(meals[:id].eq(ingredients[:meal_id])) 

    return Ingredient.find_by_sql(ingredients_for_user.to_sql)
end
```

What I'm trying to do here is get all ingredients used in all the meals offered for each restaurant the user owns. The ingredients_for_user variable represents the Arel query that I wish to run. I'm just not sure how to run & return all the ingredients, and the Ingredient.find_by_sql... just doesn't seem right.

end

Comment: Please show the code you currently have to generate the query.

Comment: @pushmatrix how can you solve this problem?

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand why you wouldn't just do the following . . .

```
Ingredient.joins({:meals=>:restaurants}).
           where(["restaurants.user_id = ?",self.id])
```

Comment: Because it's not guaranteed to use indexes in complex queries this way.

Comment: indexes have nothing to do with arel - rails doesn't interact with the query planner other than just generating string-based sql statements.

Comment: Indexes have everything to do with performance. Getting 10ms vs. 800ms   query time matters. You have to care about that.

I.e. in PostgreSQL case injecting filter in the ON statement will optimize query for filtering _before_ join. In my case reducing the dataset size significantly. Putting it into WHERE will run the filter upon the huge resulting dataset that logically has no indexes. So yes, rails does interact with planner. It submits queries.

Comment: My point was that the OP could simplify syntax by not using explicit arel tables - I agree that indexes and queries are important, and surely you agree that using explicit arel tables isn't the only way to get an efficient query.  I think we've been talking past each other.

Comment: "and surely you agree that using explicit arel tables isn't the only way to get an efficient query". That's exactly the thing I was disagreeing with. There are cases when you're limited in options. And I had to break chaining because using Arel was the only way to generate an efficient query. And answers like "you could use .where()" are not helping and are misleading.

Comment: arel doesn't control the sql query planner, it's just an interface to generate sql statements.  For any query with explicit arel tables, there is a way to construct it without explicit arel tables.

Answer (score -2):

Arel objects (or, more specifically, `Arel::Relation` objects) represent a query in relational algebra. The query is executed the first time you try to access its elements, and it acts as a result set as before.

For example, if you have a query like

```
users.join(:photos).on(users[:id].eq(photos[:user_id]))
```

you can, iterate over the photos in a view:

```
<% users.each do |user| %>
  <% users.photos.each do |photo| %>
    <%= photo.name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The example was taken from the [Arel's README](http://github.com/rails/arel), which may help you understand better.

Comment: There's a small typo in your first code example;there's not supposed to be a colon on photos. Also, I'm not sure what you're doing in the second example. Are "users" and "photos" both of type Arel::Table?

Comment: `undefined method `each' for #<Arel::SelectManager`

Answer (score -2):

Methods that return objects (like your `get_all_ingredients` method) should be class methods. It's not 100% obvious how to do this in Ruby, but one way is to use the `self.` prefix when declaring your method. (This `self.` makes sense eventually when you dive into what Rubyists often call the `eigenclass`, but for now we can just know that that's how it's done).

Here's what your method should look like in your Ingredients model:

```
def self.get_all_ingredients
    # insert your code from your question here
end
```

Then call your method in your view like:

`<%- Ingredients.get_all_ingredients.each do |current_ingredient| %>`
    `# do your things here`
  `<% end %>`